# Spring aop scoped-proxy not working on linux installation

Tags: linux, spring, aop, session-scope

I have a bean which is declared as session scoped. I had to enable aop in my configuration to use it in other beans (singletons by default).

**confi**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
         ">
    ...
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="com.my.pack.MySessionLocaleResolver" scope="session">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    </bean>
```

While I am starting it from eclipse, on my Windows desktop computer, it works just well, as it is declared.
But, when I'm publishing it on a my test, linux environment, it somehow does ignores aop thing, and throws an error

**exception in linux environment**

```
11:09:24,928 ERROR {localhost-startStop-1} [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet:initServletBean] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.localeResolver': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:343)
```

There are no additional errors in log files. Nor in a web-app log, nor in a catalina.out.
I'am using spring 3.2.4, on tomcat 7.0.42 and "CentOS release 6.5".

Answer (score 0):

Read those error messages carefully, the always contain a reason why it fails.

In this case:

```
Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread
```

which means you don't have an active HTTP session when the bean is requested.

Comment: That is the catch. The message also says _consider defining a scoped proxy_ which is exactly what I done.  But, the main question is why does it works ok on windows, and does not on linux?

Comment: There must be a difference how you compile and run the code on Linux. Since you provide no details, I can't begin to guess what might be wrong.

Comment: Deploy package is compiled with jenkins and ivy as dependency manager. When i removed scope in my xml config, application started ok, no matter I have all those aop references (ok data was mixed in my Resolver, but the app is working). It seems that all aop jars are deployed within app - aopalliance-1.0.jar, cglib-2.2.jar, spring-aop-3.2.4.jar. There are no other error except tho mentioned above. Really don't know where to look more.

Comment: The error message says that there was no current HTTP session or request at the time. Are you sure there is one?

Comment: That is correct. There are no session at the moment. The error was thrown during startup. That's why we have scoped-proxies. Error is the same as it would be if I haven't defined proxy. So it must be that tomcat wasn't loaded some of aop jars, or something like.

Comment: The bean can't be created without a session. For some reason, the startup is different on Linux and on Windows. That means you'll get the same error on Windows if you recreate the same state. The usual workaround is not to use `@Autowire`. Instead check if there is a session and if there is one, get the app context from code and then use `getBean()` to get the instance.

Comment: Yes, that would work too. But as I access to that resolver on some 10 places, it would be quite ugly solution, so I ended up with an classic session.setAttribute() solution inside my resolver. The scoped-proxy and my linux installation will stay a mystery. Thanx for help anyway.

Comment: Wrap it in a helper class so you have just a single line of code in those 10 places. It will also make it easier to fix when you finally figured out what's the difference between your Windows and Linux setup.